remove last route line if i check multiple vehicles and the other route lines still draw on map after i uncheck all vehicles
export const drawOnMap = (info, map, L) => {
  if (info?.Latitude != 0 && info?.Longitude != 0) {
    let pointA = new L.LatLng(info?.Latitude, info?.Longitude);
    let pointB = new L.LatLng(info?.current_location?.coordinates[0], info?.current_location?.coordinates[1]);
    let pointList = [pointA, pointB];

    const polyline = L.polyline(pointList, {
      color: '',
      weight: 5,
      opacity: 0.5,
      smoothFactor: 1
    }).addTo(map);

    // Fit the map to the polyline
    map.fitBounds(polyline.getBounds());

    const routingControl = L.Routing.control({
      waypoints: [
        L.latLng(info?.Latitude, info?.Longitude),
        L.latLng(info?.current_location?.coordinates[0], info?.current_location?.coordinates[1])
      ],
      router: L.Routing.osrmv1({
        serviceUrl: 'https://router.project-osrm.org/route/v1/'
      }),
      lineOptions: {
        styles: [
          { color: 'blue', weight: 4, opacity: 0.7 } // Set color to 'blue'
        ],
        summaryTemplate: null, // Disable the summary pop-up
        altLineOptions: null
      },
      show: false,
      addWaypoints: false,
      draggableWaypoints: false,
      routeWhileDragging: false,
      collapsible: true,
      autoRoute: true
    }).addTo(map);

    return { polyline, routingControl };
  }
  return null;
} function handleUnpinAndRemove(vehicleId) {
    setActiveRoutes((prevRoutes) => {
      const currentRoutes = {...prevRoutes };
      if (currentRoutes[vehicleId]) {
        // Safely remove the layer and routing control for the current vehicle
        const route = currentRoutes[vehicleId];
        if (route && route.polyline) {
          myMap.removeLayer(route.polyline);
        }
        if (route && route.routingControl) {
          route.routingControl.remove();
        }
        delete currentRoutes[vehicleId];
      }
      return currentRoutes;
    });

  }
  
  const onCheck = (selectedKeys, info) => {
    const byGroup = info.checkedNodesPositions.filter(
      (i) => i.pos.split("-").length === 2
    );
  
    if (byGroup.length > 0) {
      if (info.checked) {
        const filterParentNodes = info?.checkedNodes
          ?.filter((x) => !x.children)
          .map((i) => i?.data);
  
        filterParentNodes.forEach((x) => {
          myMap.pin(x);
          const route = drawOnMap(x, myMap, L);
          if (route) {
            setActiveRoutes((prevRoutes) => ({
              ...prevRoutes,
              [x.VehicleID]: route
            }));
          }
        });
      } else {
        if (info?.node?.data?.children) {
          info?.node?.data?.children.forEach((x) => {
            myMap.unpin(x?.VehicleID);
            handleUnpinAndRemove(x?.VehicleID);
          });
        } else {
          myMap.unpin(info?.node?.data?.VehicleID);
          handleUnpinAndRemove(info?.node?.data?.VehicleID);
        }
      }
    } else if (info.checkedNodes.length > 0) {
      if (info.checked) {
        const filterParentNodes = info?.checkedNodes
          ?.filter((x) => !x.children)
          .map((i) => i?.data);
  
        filterParentNodes.forEach((x) => {
          myMap.pin(x);
          const route = drawOnMap(x, myMap, L);
          if (route) {
            setActiveRoutes((prevRoutes) => ({
              ...prevRoutes,
              [x.VehicleID]: route
            }));
          }
        });
      } else {
        myMap.unpin(info?.node?.data?.VehicleID);
        handleUnpinAndRemove(info?.node?.data?.VehicleID);
      }
    } else {
      if (!info?.node?.data?.children) {
        myMap.unpin(info?.node?.data?.VehicleID);
        handleUnpinAndRemove(info?.node?.data?.VehicleID);
      } else {
        myMap.deselectAll(true);
      }
    }
  };

When I check an item from the vehicle list, the vehicle appears in the map and if I uncheck it, it is unpinned from the map and if I select a multiple vehicles  and I need to uncheck or unpin the vehicle it is unpinned successfully but the last vehicle I chose the route line is removed and what There are still other things in the map, let's see I have checked four vehicles and the road line of four items is shown and if you deselect them all, the last road line will be removed and the other one will remain in the map
